# get $_GET and $_POST values, but not $_COOKIE values

Tags: php, superglobals

I would like to use $_REQUEST, but I don't want the value if it came from a cookie.  What is the best way to do this?  This is how I currently do it.  Thanks

```
$value=isset($_GET['name'])?$_GET['name']:(isset($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:NULL);
```

Comment: Any reason why you want to use $_REQUEST and not specifically $_GET or $_POST?

Comment: Because my code doesn't care where it came from as long as it was one of those two.  For other aspects, I very do need to know if it is POST, but this is not one of them.  Thanks

Comment: If you _never_ want a `$_COOKIE` array... you can change `variables_order` to exclude it, so it won't read that for `$_REQUEST`, but also won't make the superglobal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to use $_REQUEST, but I don't want the value if it came from a cookie.

Those are two mutually-exclusive statements, I'm afraid.  According to [the PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), `$_REQUEST` is:

> An associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

If you only want to use `$_GET` and `$_POST` and *explicitly* don't want `$_COOKIE` then you'll have to use them individually.

In general it's a good idea to abstract infrastructure dependencies anyway, so you can make a function (or, better yet, an object) which gets the values you're looking for.  Maybe something as simple as this:

```
function getRequestValue($name) {
    if (isset($_GET[$name])) {
        return $_GET[$name];
    }
    if (isset($_POST[$name])) {
        return $_POST[$name];
    }
    // throw an error?  return a default value or null?
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, you and John think alike!

Answer (score 1):

Just make a function that does this logic for you:

```
function fromCookielessRequest($key) {
    if (isset($_GET[$key])) {
        return $_GET[$key];
    }
    if (isset($_POST[$key])) {
        return $_POST[$key];
    }
    return null;
}

$name     = fromCookielessRequest('name');
$password = fromCookielessRequest('password');
```

Comment: Thanks John,  Looks like I must continue doing it similar to how I had been.